# Encoding query parameters in URL using Java with valid charset

Tags: java, decode, encode, urlencode, rest

I am trying to understand what is the difference and importance of different charsets available while encoding and decoding text.

I have a scenario, where I want to call a RestAPI. The RestAPI has a base URL, for ex: `https://myrestapiurl.com`. Now to perform a `GET` request, the URL is formed by appending the `id` of the entity that I want to fetch, like: https://myrestapiurl.com('id')

`id` : It has no limitations on **valid characters**!

I have encountered an id: `باقی ریسورس` , So before calling the RestAPI, I need to encode it. Using Java's URLEncoder, I tried the following:

```
 String s ="باقی ریسورس";
 String encodedID = URLEncoder.encode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() )
```

Using the encodedID, I try to make a request using `PostMan`. The request fails with `404 or 400` when I use different charset. It only succeeds when I encode using `ISO_8859_1` as follows:

```
 String encodedID = URLEncoder.encode(s, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());
 String URL = "https://myrestapiurl.com('" + encodedID + "')";
```

This works fine, through code as well as PostMan. My question is:

How can I decide which charset to use before encoding? `Or should I have fallbacks`? That is if it fails with `UTF_8 then try with UTF_16` etc etc...**but this is very in-efficient**. In case if the entity actually doesn't exist, then, these tries would be overhead

Also, when I visit https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP and enter the text to be encoded, it provides the valid encoded string with `ISO_8859_1` , how does it manage to do so?

How can this be done in Java without using any other extra libraries like `apache`? We don't have choice to add extra dependencies!

Comment: I suspect the server is hardcoded to ISO-8859-1 (probably Windows) and I don't know if there's anything you can do to determine that ahead of time.

Comment: Then how does https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP give the right encoded value before hand, and also Postman doesn't through any error and when the non-encoded URL is hit? https://myrestapiurl.com('باقی ریسورس')